# Getting the value of the property using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to get the value of the property by name in a class instance. I found a lot of solutions on the net to solve the problem in a way like this:

```
var value = (int)userData.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(userData, null);
```

or

```
var value = (int)GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(userData, null);
```

but the compiler notifies me `NullReferenceException` in that line (the second parameter should be null if the desired property is not an array which is not).

Please help,

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think null refers to failure to retrieve property with name "id". what does that property look like in your code ?

Comment: please show us what type is `userData` and it's structure.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your Id property has the `private` or `protected` modifier. Then you have to use the first overload of the `GetProperty` method:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id1").GetValue(t, null));
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id2").GetValue(t, null));
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id3").GetValue(t, null));

        //the next line will throw a NullReferenceExcption
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id4").GetValue(t, null));
        //this line will work
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id4",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(t, null));


        //the next line will throw a NullReferenceException
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id5").GetValue(t, null));
         //this line will work
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().GetProperty("Id5", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(t, null));
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            Id1 = 1;
            Id2 = 2;
            Id3 = 3;
            Id4 = 4;
            Id5 = 5;
        }

        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { private get; set; }
        public int Id3 { get; private set; }
        protected int Id4 { get; set; }
        private int Id5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you have `public` properties you can use the new `dynamic` keyword:

```
static void Main()
{
    dynamic s = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(s.Id1);
    Console.WriteLine(s.Id3);
}
```

Note that `Id2, Id4 and Id5` won't work with the `dynamic` keyword, because they do not have a public acessor.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will fail if userData doesn't have the "id" property. Try with this:

```
var selectedProperty = from property in this.GetType().GetProperties()
                       where property.Name == "id" 
                       select property.GetValue(this, null);
```

This way you'll never retrieve the value of a Null property.

p.s. Are you sure "id" is a property and not a field?

Comment: Yes, you are right, my UserData.id is a field not the property. It is designated with public modifier. Can I retrieve the value from it without setting the get and set methods?

Comment: @user3040712 you mostly do the same but with  `GetField("id")`

Answer (score -1):

For getting the propery value from the calss can simply access as below,

userData.id;